# Solr returns top rank not exact match for term 101 it returns S101

Tags: solr, search-engine, solrnet

I have eCommerce indexed data with field name PartNumber (Item Numbers), and the data flushed daily.

**Field type** in solr is **text** because the field may contains numbers, characters or special chars like dash.

When I search with term like:

> 192.168.x.x:xx/solr/keyword/select?q=**(PartNumber:101)^2.0+OR+(101)**&start=0&rows=20&spellcheck=true&version=2.2&debug=true&fl=*,score

query result returns: first 20 row:

> - S101
> - 1014
> - **101**
> - 101S
> - 101U

**I have Tried PartNumber:"101" and 101 the same result always returns where 101 is not top ranked.**

**Note:** If the term is 4 characters or more (5000,16400,K5125,..etc) the top result is better and usually the exact match is the first one.

*Some of debug results:*

```
<lst name="debug">
<str name="rawquerystring">(PartNumber:101)^2.0 OR (101)</str><str name="querystring">(PartNumber:101)^2.0 OR (101)</str>
<str name="parsedquery">PhraseQuery(PartNumber:"1 10 101"^2.0) PhraseQuery(text:"1 10 101")</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">PartNumber:"1 10 101"^2.0 text:"1 10 101"</str><lst name="explain">
<str name="40541432">
6.7604995 = (MATCH) sum of:
  5.1748066 = (MATCH) weight(PartNumber:"1 10 101"^2.0 in 492450) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
    5.1748066 = score(doc=492450,freq=1.0 = phraseFreq=1.0
), product of:
      0.91124594 = queryWeight, product of:
        2.0 = boost
        11.357651 = idf(), sum of:
          1.5469646 = idf(docFreq=797168, maxDocs=1377508)
          3.6602204 = idf(docFreq=96332, maxDocs=1377508)
          6.1504664 = idf(docFreq=7984, maxDocs=1377508)
        0.040115952 = queryNorm
      5.6788254 = fieldWeight in 492450, product of:
        1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
          1.0 = phraseFreq=1.0
        11.357651 = idf(), sum of:
          1.5469646 = idf(docFreq=797168, maxDocs=1377508)
          3.6602204 = idf(docFreq=96332, maxDocs=1377508)
          6.1504664 = idf(docFreq=7984, maxDocs=1377508)
        0.5 = fieldNorm(doc=492450)
  1.5856929 = (MATCH) weight(text:"1 10 101" in 492450) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
    1.5856929 = score(doc=492450,freq=4.0 = phraseFreq=4.0
), product of:
      0.4118627 = queryWeight, product of:
        10.266806 = idf(), sum of:
          1.407141 = idf(docFreq=916800, maxDocs=1377508)
          3.1487658 = idf(docFreq=160655, maxDocs=1377508)
          5.7108994 = idf(docFreq=12392, maxDocs=1377508)
        0.040115952 = queryNorm
      3.850052 = fieldWeight in 492450, product of:
        2.0 = tf(freq=4.0), with freq of:
          4.0 = phraseFreq=4.0
        10.266806 = idf(), sum of:
          1.407141 = idf(docFreq=916800, maxDocs=1377508)
          3.1487658 = idf(docFreq=160655, maxDocs=1377508)
          5.7108994 = idf(docFreq=12392, maxDocs=1377508)
        0.1875 = fieldNorm(doc=492450)
</str>
```

Comment: What is the field type and definition of PartNumber , it looks like the problem is not with your query. It looks like has to do with how the field is analyzed (are you using ngram etc?) both during indexing and query time.

Comment: Field type is text the same default with fiters:
<fieldType name="textsort" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">

Comment: tokenizers: 

**In Indexing:** StopFilterFactory,WordDelimiterFilterFactory,LowerCaseFilterFactory,KeywordMarkerFilterFactory,PorterStemFilterFactory,RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory

**In query:** WhitespaceTokenizerFactory, SynonymFilterFactory, StopFilterFactory, WordDelimiterFilterFactory, LowerCaseFilterFactory, KeywordMarkerFilterFactory, PorterStemFilterFactory, RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory

Answer (score 1):

Without know your field definition for PartNumber , my speculative answer is that it looks like you are indexing and querying based on ngram kind of analysis. If you need to use ngram that is fine , do it during indexing. But during query time analysis ngram can give this type of results, in this case parts of 101 are perfectly good matches and are same as 101S , if you think about it in its parts.

After looking at your field definition , i am not sure if you need PorterStemFilterFactory during query time, may be it is droping 101s to 101? use analysis page from admin panel to check how the index and query data are processed for your needs.

Comment: ranking is better now but still not as it should (`the first result still S101`), I had to do queries through **UnTokenized fields** to get matching numbers in to ranks.